# Is there any way to store files locally using Opera's user javascript?

Tags: opera, userscripts

Is there some way to download and store files in a specific, developer-defined location using Opera's user javascript functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Opera User Javascript: http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/userjs/

Comment: I didn't know it existed

Comment: @Nifle: They haven't mentioned anything about persistent storage in files (not cookies).

Comment: See what they've got for Unite service (maybe it'll work in UserJS too). And check if they've implemented HTML 5 persistent storage yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, a pure JavaScript solution for this is only possible with widgets and Opera 10 and greater. It should be possible to interact with a Java applet the user has granted sufficient privileges to save files though. I've also seen a solution that used a local server which the user.js would talk to - see the "HistoryPlus" script described somewhere in this post:

http://my.opera.com/chooseopera/forums/findpost.pl?id=2669972

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.opera.com/libraries/fileio/docs/overview-summary-file-io.js.dml looks like what you want.

```
var localDir, remoteFile;
var out = serverDir.open(remoteFile, opera.io.filemode.READ);
var in = clientDir.open(localFile, opera.io.filemode.WRITE);
var line = "";
do {
in.writeLine(line);
line = out.readLine();
} while(line);
in.close();
out.close();
```

The user has to change their config file to allow for these libraries.

Comment: Seems like it's only for Opera Widgets, and not Opera User Scripts.